# Unity3D to Raspberry Pi Server Connection Failed to Respond

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, raspberry-pi

So yesterday I had all this working on a Raspberry Pi talking to Unity (Python 2.7 on Pi, Unity 2017) then the memory card failed and I had to build a new one. The new install is Python 3.5 and same Unity as before. The code I wrote I think is roughly the same though with troubleshooting it's gotten changed a bit (print statements changed etc for 3.5). Either way I'm getting an error on the Unity side saying the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time. I've pinged the IP and the socket from the PC and also other computers and it's accessible but just the Unity application won't talk to the Pi Server. Can someone see where I've messed up in my code? Firewall is disabled on the PC and the IP/Port addresses for the Pi are correct.

**Python on Raspberry Pi**

```
import socket
import sys

backlog = 1
size = 1024
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('192.168.3.232', 12345))
s.listen(1)

while True:
    print ('waiting for a connection')
    connection, client_address = s.accept()

try:
    print ('connection from', client_address)
    while True:
        data = connection.recv(16)
        print ('received "%s"' % data)
        if data:
            print ('sending data back to the client')
            connection.sendall(data)
        else:
            print ('no more data from', client_address)
            break

finally:
    print("closing socket")
    cient.close()
    s.close()
```

**C# on Unity**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets; 

public class ClientSocket : MonoBehaviour {

 bool socketReady = false;
 TcpClient mySocket;
 public NetworkStream theStream;
 StreamWriter theWriter;
 StreamReader theReader;
 public String Host = "192.168.3.232";
 public Int32 Port = 12345;     

 void Start() {
     setupSocket ();
 }


 public void setupSocket() {                            // Socket setup here
     try {                
         mySocket = new TcpClient(Host, Port);
         theStream = mySocket.GetStream();
         theWriter = new StreamWriter(theStream);
         theReader = new StreamReader(theStream);
         socketReady = true;
     }
     catch (Exception e) {
         Debug.Log("Socket error:" + e);                // catch any exceptions
     }
 }
```

Error from Unity console:
Socket error:System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Comment: is the ip address correct?

Comment: Yes responding to pings also to confirm

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the firewall on the Raspberry Pi is still on. Check your iptables. 
You can test that if you make a small sockettest application in python on your Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I've run 'sudo iptables -L -nv' and come back empty so the firewall is disabled unless there's something hidden somewhere else.

Comment: In addition when I do a sockettest I get a rather strange one (using the local machine and changing the server address to 127.0.0.1) if I check 'netstat -lptn' when the server script starts it shows the port open and all looks correct, the second I do a socket test it shuts the port and kicks up the following error: something's wrong with 127.0.0.1:12345. Exception is [Errno 111] Connection refused'

Answer (score 0):

@ Colin. I copied and pasted your Python code into Python 2.7.9 running on my Raspberry Pi and also your Client Socket in Unity running on my PC and it works fine. Simply changed the IP address and all worked fine. I know this is a late response but it may help someone else.